# reactstrap navbar header seems to be missing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

I'm currently trying to create a navbar using reactstrap and I would like to use a

```html
<div className="navbar-header">
</div>
```

which would map to a Navbar.Header in React-Bootstrap.

Unfortunately I cannot find such component in reactstrap. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Kind sir:

React doesn't quite work the way you are trying to use it...Well, it WILL use it, if you load the CDN into the header on your index.html. If you are using reactstrap or react-bootstrap, you would load them as a custom component.

To load a button in react-bootstrap, you first would import it:

`import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'`

and in your code you would call it like this:

`<Button bsStyle="warning" bsSize="large"> Button! </Button>`

this is the react method for calling something you would do in normal html like this:

`<button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning> Button! </button>`

You still need to load the css from either locally or the CDN  in the index.html (normally kept in public/index.html).

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html

Answer (score -2):

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar color="faded" light expand="md">
          <NavbarBrand href="/">reactstrap</NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/components/">Components</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">Github</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
                <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                  Options
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu >
                  <DropdownItem>
                    Option 1
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem>
                    Option 2
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem divider />
                  <DropdownItem>
                    Reset
                  </DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
              </UncontrolledDropdown>
            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
<!--Navbar Properties-->
Navbar.propTypes = {
  light: PropTypes.bool,
  dark: PropTypes.bool,
  fixed: PropTypes.string,
  color: PropTypes.string,
  role: PropTypes.string,
  expand: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.bool, PropTypes.string]),
  tag: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.string])
  // pass in custom element to use
}
<!--NavbarBrand Properties-->
NavbarBrand.propTypes = {
  tag: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.string])
  // pass in custom element to use
}
<!--NavbarToggler-->
import React from 'react';
import { Collapse, Navbar, NavbarToggler, NavbarBrand, Nav, NavItem, NavLink } from 'reactstrap';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggleNavbar = this.toggleNavbar.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      collapsed: true
    };
  }

  toggleNavbar() {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar color="faded" light>
          <NavbarBrand href="/" className="mr-auto">reactstrap</NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleNavbar} className="mr-2" />
          <Collapse isOpen={!this.state.collapsed} navbar>
            <Nav navbar>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/components/">Components</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">Github</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
<!--NavbarToggler Properties-->
NavbarToggler.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string,
  tag: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.string])
  // pass in custom element to use
}
```